# Hide String in UIActivityViewController from User

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, uiactivityviewcontroller

I would like to pass a string to a `UIActivityViewController` but hide it from the user when they publish a tweet or share on Facebook.

In the free version of my app, the added hidden string will be '*Download my app now!*', whereas in the paid version (via in-app purchase), this string will not be published.

In the free version, the user must not be able to delete the added string.  But I can't find a way to hide it from them.  So when they share, that pop-up appears and the string is included, editable.  This is my code so far:

```
NSString *advertString = @"Download my app now!";

UIActivityViewController *shareController =
    [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
     initWithActivityItems:@[scoreString, advertString, url, image]
     applicationActivities:nil];
```

How would I go about doing this?  Or are there alternatives that would allow me to do this?  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a subject for your email by implementing

```
- (NSString *)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController subjectForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType;
```

in a class that conforms to the`UIActivityItemSource` protocol. See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityItemSource_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIActivityItemSource/activityViewController%3AsubjectForActivityType%3A) for more information.

**Edited**
You need to customize this by using different string on different sharing option.
Read this [Tutorial](http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/), this will work.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks but how do I hide a string from a tweet?

Comment: @user3127576: Answer Edited, kindly look into that tutorial, hope this will work. Thanks.